# How to redirect or block cloudfront url when query param not found

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I have the s3 resource mapped in cloudfront to cache image, i´m trying to redirect to another page, unsuccesfully.

The cloufront URL is similar on bellow

http://d39o2548cde2323.cloudfront.net/product_images/1/7895000483853/7895000483853_1_1_1200_72_RGB.png?**pid=12&cmid=12&hash=12314121cwdfiwjdif**

product_images/1/7895000483853/7895000483853_1_1_1200_72_RGB.png -> s3 object
pid=12&cmid=12&hash=12314121cwdfiwjdif -> params in url

**I need block show or download the s3 image mapped by clound when the pid, and cmid or another params was not found.**

I created a lambda edge and set in behavior in cloudfront trigger, but the page didn´t redirect.

My lambda code is like as bellow:

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    console.log("request.uri " + request.uri);
    console.log("request.querystring " + request.querystring);
    
    console.log("##############################################");
    console.log("################# CLOUDFRONT S3  #############################");
    console.log("##############################################");

    if (request.querystring.includes("pid") && request.querystring.includes("cmid")) {
        console.log("OK contains params");
        callback(null, request);
        return;
    }else{
        console.log("ERROR not contains params");
        const redirectResponse = {
        status: '403',
        statusDescription: 'Not Allowed',
        headers: {
          'location': [{
            key: 'Location',
            value: '/403/index.html',
          }],
          'cache-control': [{
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: "max-age=3600"
          }],
        },
        };
        console.log("Redirecting");
        callback(null, redirectResponse);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> *the page didn´t redirect*

You aren't returning a redirect, you're returning `status: '403'` which is an error response meaning `Forbidden`.  The `Location` header has no meaning in this case.

Change the `status` code to 302 or 307 assuming a redirect is what you want.  I'm not entirely sure it is, because a redirect -- by definition -- changes the URL in the browser's address bar.

Comment: you are right! i change the code and the page was redirect, my problem now is always redirect page

Comment: Okay, check your Lambda logs to see what's going on.  You might also want to modify the code to log the value of `request.querystring`.  You may find that it is empty because you did not configure CloudFront to forward the querystring to the origin.  That's required, if this is an Origin Request trigger.

Comment: Well i need block content if the certain query string like a token not found in query params, if exists save paras in a dynamodb table, Is this a best way? blocking using a lambda edge origin request and save in another lambda origem response trigger?